# Is it premature optimisation to test a condition to skip a small loop?

Tags: javascript, optimization, typescript

I have an array of entities which have an `id` property:

```
entities: {id: string|null}[] = [];
```

All items in the array are guaranteed to have `id !== null` and the array will not exceed 100 items.

Now I *may* want to find a specific item based on a condition:

```
const id: string|null = condition ? value : null;
```

My quesiton is: Is it ok to simply run:

```
const entity: Entity|undefined = entities.find(entity => entitiy.id === id);
```

… or should I in any case increase the code size by using this and make the code more resilient:

```
const entity: Entity|undefined = id ? entities.find(entity => entitiy.id === id) : undefined;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's one of those cases when making the code cleaner, will actually make it faster too

> Now I may want to find a specific item based on a condition:
>
> const id: string|null = condition ? value : null;

The problem is that you give `null` a special implicit meaning of "don't look up the entity".

A cleaner solution would be something like

```
if (condition) {
  const id = value;
  doStuffWithEntity(id, entities.find(entity => entitiy.id === id))
} else {
  doStuffWithoutEntity()
}
```

This might lead to other problems, tho... But note that `id` and `entity` depend on the same condition, and it's probably better to handle them as such, instead of using `id == null` as an intermediate condition